# MapServer query through URL

Tags: mapserver

I am new to MapServer and I wanted to host offline map server on Windows, so after following this link https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/wiki/RenderingOsmDataWindows#osm-import
I have setup the map for only India.

and with the below URL I can get a map of India, but I can't zoom in. How can I get to a particular lat long at center with some zoom value using URL parameters?

http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?mode=browse&template=openlayers&layers=all&map=C:/ms4w/apps/osm/basemaps/osm-google.map

Answer (score 1):

Check out the mapserver doc page: https://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html

Specifically the bbox parameter:

```
BBOX=minx,miny,maxx,maxy
```

seen here in a url (copied from docs):

```
http://my.host.com/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=mywms.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1
 &REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=prov_bound&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG:4326
 &BBOX=-173.537,35.8775,-11.9603,83.8009&WIDTH=400&HEIGHT=300
 &FORMAT=image/png
```

The BBOX is the geographic rectangle you want(note the center is the middle of the bbox) to be included in your map.
How you actually get the bbox manually is up to you...usually a tool like openlayers or leaflet keeps track for you.